# Get fail constraint name from DataIntegrityViolationException with spring-data-r2dbc and postgresql

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have some constraints in a postgresql database (unique, foreign key...).

I use spring data r2dbc repository : `ReactiveCrudRepository`

I would like to transform the `DataIntegrityViolationException` throw by the repository to some custom exception based on the `constraintName` in `ErrorDetails` field of `PostgresqlDataIntegrityViolationException`.

But `ExceptionFactory` class containing the `PostgresqlDataIntegrityViolationException` is package private. So I can't cast the cause exception of `DataIntegrityViolationException` to `PostgresqlDataIntegrityViolationException`.

What is the cleanest way to access to the `constraintName` when I catch a `DataIntegrityViolationException` ?

(something better than parsing the exception message ^^)

**edit :**

I'm ended with this solution :

```java
    val DataIntegrityViolationException.pgErrorDetails: ErrorDetails
        get() = when(val cause = this.cause) {
                null -> error("cause should not be null")
                else -> cause.javaClass
                        .getDeclaredField("errorDetails")
                        .apply { isAccessible = true }
                        .let { it.get(cause) as ErrorDetails }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Myr2dbcRepo.save(myEntity).doOnError(cause -> {
     PostgresqlException pe =(PostgresqlException) cause.getCause();
     ErrorDetails ed = pe.getErrorDetails();
 }).suscribe();
```

Take into account that DataIntegrityViolationException is just a spring boot wrapper for the dbDriver's Exceptions you're using, in this case R2DBC.

Also you may need to change the scope of R2DBC-POSTGRES dependency from "runtime" to "implementation".

Finally notice my code example is on java, I'm sure you won't have efforts translating it to kotlin.